# Why not always use Public Functions and Variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm writing a flash game in actionscript 3.  In one of my MovieClip classes, I began coding by writing a few functions and variables.  So we all know that private functions and variables cannot be accessed outside of the MovieClip, while public functions and variables can.

So here comes my question:  Why do we not just *always* use public functions?  Does it cause latency problems?  Does it return a specific value that makes it public which makes the player do more work?

Also, if you're not writing in a class and putting frame code, the functions are always public.  Why is this?  Why not let private functions and variables in frame actions, too, for whatever reason in my first question's answer?

Comment: What is relationship between latency and public specifier ?

Comment: @kirugan Maybe the player has to do more work by making it accessible by the MovieClip's parent?  I'm not sure, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I dont know who downvoted my post but I have suspicions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing Object Oriented design you will be finding you are writing you code in a class file.
When you make a method Public, you are explicitly saying, use this method from outside my class to help achieve your goal.

Use private methods to help prevent any confusing for anyone (eg yourself) for saying, don't use this method oustide my class. This method is for this call and dont try and use it.

eg.

```
public function deleteAllUsers():void{
    // 1. check user is logged in
    // 2. check users are not active
    // 3. clean up another object.
    // 4. call _deteleAllusers
} 

private function _deleteAllUsers(){
    // delete from users (do no error checking.
}
```

From the above example, calling deleteAllUsers does a lot of checking.
But making the method _deteleAllUsers private you cannot skip the error checking and this method is only used internally by the class once we are ready to delete the users.

Cheers, John.

Answer (score 7):

You can use all public if you want.

Suppose your code was a McDonalds and you were the manager. You make things that the customers need `public`, such as the tables, chairs, and the free refill soda machines. However, there are things that a customer doesn't need access to, and you have those things in a `private` area locked off by an **Employees Only** door.  You don't want people with no knowledge or need to be in your kitchen, potentially screwing something up.

It's good practice to only expose things that need to be exposed, and that reduces the chances of it's inner workings being compromised. It's more important when you are working with a large code base and a team of people working together. If it's all your code and you are the only one who'll ever see it, it's not likely going to matter as much. However using public/private to expose/restrict properties/methods can make your life easier as it's less clutter when working with an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind not always using public access is because even though it is A LOT more convienient when wanting to use one class with another, it also can make things confusing. There are going to be items you need, as well as ones you dont. Why have ones that aren't needed? They should be put away and left to themselves. This is simply what private variables are. They are not allowed to interact, so it allows the more important stuff to communicate. I hope that helps with the confusion.